# One dropdown down depends on two dropdowns in codeigniter with

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, dropdown, dependent-type

Here I have Two independent dropdowns : "Sub company " and " Role"  and there is a third dropdown which depends on these two dropdowns. basically what I want to implement is if the chosen "Role" is NOT 'manager' and 'admin', then displays third dropdown "manager", which its options depends on sub company .
Right now I am able to get all the managers depends on sub company , what I need to do is to make a condition to only show managers list  when role !== 'manager' &&  role !== 'admin'.
Here is the view.php

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="pwd">Sub Company Name</label>
               <div class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('Subcom'); ?></div>
              <select  class="form-control" id="Subcom"  name="Subcom" >
              <option value="">Select Sub Company</option>
              <?php 
                    
            foreach($company_name as $row )
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$row->company_name.'" '.set_select('Subcom', $row->company_name).'>'.$row->company_name.'</option>';
             }
            ?> 
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="pwd">Role</label>
              <div class="alert-danger"> <?php echo form_error('role'); ?></div>
              <select class="form-control" id="role" name="role" placeholder="Select Role">
               <option value="">Select Role</option></div>
                 <?php 
                    
            foreach($role_name as $row )
            {
               echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'" '.set_select('role', $row->role_name).'>'.$row->role_name.'</option>';
             }
            ?>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4"  >
              <label  for="pwd">Manager</label>
              <div class="alert-danger">  <?php echo form_error('manager'); ?></div>
              <select class="form-control" id="manager" name="manager"  placeholder="Select Manager" style="display:none"  disabled>
             <option value="">Select Manager</option>
             </select>
            </div>
```

And here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(' #Subcom, #role').on('change' , function() {
  var company_name = $('#Subcom').val();
  var role = $('#role').val();
 if( company_name!==''&& role !== '' && role !=='manager' && role !== 
  'admin')
  {
  //alert('ok');
  $('#manager').prop('disabled', false);
   
   $.ajax({
     url:"<?php echo base_url()?>getManager",
     type: "POST",
     data: { 'company_name' : company_name},
     dataType:'json',
     success: function(data){
       
       console.log(data);
       false;
       $('#manager').html(data.manager);  
       $('#manager').show();

     },
     error: function(event){
       console.log(event);
      alert('Error occur...');
     }
    
   });
}else {
//alert('sgsg');
  $('#manager').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#manager').hide();
  }
 });
});

</script>
```

Here is the controller

```
 public function getManager()
{
  //echo json_encode ($_REQUEST); die; 
   //print_r($_REQUEST);
    //die;
  $company_name = $this->input->post('company_name');
  $getallmanager = $this->project_model->get_manager_query($company_name);
  $getallstaff = $this->project_model->get_all_staff($company_name);
  $all_the_mangers = '';
  $all_the_staffs = '';
  if(count($getallmanager)>0)
  {        
    foreach ($getallmanager as $manager){
      //if(role!=='manager')
      $all_the_mangers .='<option value="' .$manager->first_name.'">'.$manager->first_name.'</option>';
      
    }
    
  }
  if(count($getallstaff)>0)
  {        
    foreach ($getallstaff as $staff){
      $all_the_staffs .='<option value="' .$staff->first_name.'">'.$staff->first_name.'</option>';
    }
    
  }
  $result = array('manager'=>$all_the_mangers,'staffs'=>$all_the_staffs);
  echo json_encode($result);die;
  
}
```

}

And here is the Model:

```
 public function get_manager_query($company_name)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user_login', array('company_name' => $company_name,'role'=>'manager'));
    return $query->result();
} 
 public function get_all_staff($company_name)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user_login', array('company_name' => $company_name,'role !='=>'manager'));
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="display:none"` and `disabled` to manager select so it won't show up at load. Also selects don't need a value, if you want to set a specific option than you need to do it in the loops like this:

```
foreach($company_name as $row )
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row->company_name.'" '.set_select('Subcom', $row->company_name).'>'.$row->company_name.'</option>';
}
```

Also it would be a good idea to move the form errors before the select and not wrap the options with it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Subcom,#role').on('change' , function() {
        var company_name = $('#Subcom').val();
        var role_name = $('#role').val();

        if(company_name !== '' && role_name !== 'manager' && role_name !== 'admin')
        {
            $('#manager' ).prop('disabled', false);

            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url()?>getManager",
                type: "POST",
                data: { 'company_name' : company_name},
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data){
                //alert('ok');
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#manager').html(data.manager);
                    $('#manager').show();
                },
                error: function(event){
                    console.log(event);
                    alert('Error occur...');
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#manager').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#manager').hide();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

EDIT: for future reference here's the final code
https://jsfiddle.net/Lo50z6q8/

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explanation, i updated my code according your advice , but its not working, the manager select box is not displays in any condition , can you please have look

Comment: Do you get ajax console.log? Also check your html. You might not closed some tags or changed some id. If still not working post your updated codes

Comment: yes i do, I already updated my code here , please have a look

Comment: Array ( [Uname] => maedi [Fname] => madi [Lname] => SOLI [Mobno] => 0987654321 [Email] => eddysolhjoo44@gmail.com [Emp_id] => 22 [Status] => Active [Subcom] => company [role] => manager [manager] => MANI [create] => )

Comment: It is basically still getting  manager for all roles, and manager dropdown is not displaying  in view

Comment: Ahh I see. Remove the `style="display:none" disabled` from the last div and add it to the `<select>` instead. Also check the end of javascript where you misspelled '$("manager") .hid()'

Comment: Ok , now Im getting the manager dropdown, but still is just dependents only on company_name, basically it doesnt check the  role_name

Comment: You might have misstyped something. Here's a working fiddle check out this. Also I just realized you add a null option for role select as well so added it to the script `role !== ''`. [https://jsfiddle.net/Lo50z6q8/](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo50z6q8/)

Comment: I am sure your answer is currect but Ive checked all the spelling and  still it is not working, by selecting company actually $('#manager').prop('disabled', true); and by selecting role  $('#manager').prop('disabled', false); and it basically doesnt check the conditions rol!=="mangaer" and role!=="admin", do you have any idea what is the problem

Comment: No idea. Update your html and js with the latest code you have in your question and will try to check again.

Comment: I have updated the code , please have look.thank you

Comment: Solved thank you very much. the problem was from my database

Answer (score 0):

it is simply pass a var to show or hide.

in your `controller` file pass `data['role_admin'] = 1;`

in your `view` file

```
if($role_admin==1){ 
  // show your Manager code
}
```